# Text Erased in Duplicate Window with RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, C#, WPF, XAML.

This is example code to a larger project.

I have a `button` that opens a `Window` with a `RichTextBox` with the message `"Hello, World"`.

I press the `button` again, a duplicate `Window` opens but erases the text in the previous `Window`.

I think that's because both `Windows`'s `RichTextBox` has the same `x:Name="rtbMessage"`.

How can I prevent text from getting erased in the previous `Window`?

---

**Download Example:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq3x9fsaoclhxzm/RichTextBoxNewWindow.zip?dl=0

[image: RichTextBox New Window]

---

#### MainWidow

**XAML**

```
<Button x:Name="btnMessage" 
        Content="Message" 
        Margin="231,264,211,29" 
        Width="75" 
        Click="btnMessage_Click"/>
```

**C#**

```
public MessageWindow messagewindow;

// Button
// Open Message Window
//
private void btnMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainwindow = this;

    messagewindow = new MessageWindow(mainwindow);
    messagewindow.Left = mainwindow.Left + 90;
    messagewindow.Top = mainwindow.Top + 98;
    messagewindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(mainwindow);
    messagewindow.Show();
}
```

---

#### MessageWindow

**XAML**

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbMessage" 
             Margin="10,10,10,50" />
```

**C#**

```
public static Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

// Write Message to RichTextBox when MessageWindow Opens
//
public MessageWindow(MainWindow mainwindow)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Clear old text to prevent doubling up
    rtbScript.Document = new FlowDocument(p);
    rtbScript.BeginChange();
    rtbScript.SelectAll();
    rtbScript.Selection.Text = "";
    rtbScript.EndChange();

    // Write Message
    rtbScript.Document = new FlowDocument(p);
    rtbScript.BeginChange();
    p.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello, world."));
    rtbScript.EndChange();
}
```

Comment: Where is `MessageView` being called?

Comment: @BenderBending That was a typo, supposed to be `MessageWindow`.

Comment: Do you need your Paragraph to be `static`?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I removed `static`. That's what was causing the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we spoke in the comments.
The cause of the issue was static variable in your class definition.
Event though you had created the new object of that class the variable is shared and therefore overwritten on every call to that window messages.
As to why it is not updated in the first window I am not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `MessageWindow` outside of your event. Try declaring it inside the Button click event:

```
// Button
// Open Message Window
private void buttonMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainwindow = this;

    MessageWindow messagewindow = new MessageWindow(mainwindow);
    messagewindow.Left = mainwindow.Left + 90;
    messagewindow.Top = mainwindow.Top + 98;
    messagewindow.Owner = Window.GetWindow(mainwindow);
    messagewindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: Gave the same result, text gets erased.

Comment: Can you add some break points to `buttonMessage_Click` and step though when the second window is supposed to be written on?

Comment: I added the breakpoints, I was not able to tell. I imagine it's written at `MessageWindow messagewindow = new MessageWindow(mainwindow);`. You can download the example project if you want to try.